# how to calculate time taken by a method in nanoseconds in j2me platform?

Tags: java-me

I was tried to calculate time taken by a method in nanoseconds in j2me platform. But I didn't find any function to do this.

Only `System.currentTimeMillis()` function is available in j2me. But I want to calculate time in nano seconds. Can anyone please help me in this.

And, I tried `System.nanoSeconds()` in j2me, but this function is not available.

Comment: Thank you for response... I am getting results like 0, 1, 0, 0 (milli seconds) when i am using currentTimeMillis(). So, I want to use nano seconds function if available.... Thank you.